# Type Hinting: Argument Of Type Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I'm defining a method

```
def foo_my_class(my_class: ???, bar: str) -> None:
    """ Operate on my_class """
```

I wonder, how can I use type hinting feature to specify that class should be passed in the first argument.

Basically, what should I put instead of `???` mark up there?

Here is some more code to be more specific on what I am trying to achieve.

```
class Base(object):
   """base class"""

class X(Base):
    """some class"""

class Y(Base):
    """some other class"""   

foo_my_class(X, "foo")    
foo_my_class(Y, "bar")
```

Answer (score -11, accepted):

You just use the class itself.

```
def foo_my_class(my_class: MyClass, bar: str) -> None:
```

From [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#acceptable-type-hints) (emphasis mine):

> Type hints may be built-in classes (including those defined in standard library or third-party extension modules), abstract base classes, types available in the `types` module, and **user-defined classes** (including those defined in the standard library or third-party modules).

Comment: I've updated my question. It seems your solution works if I my_class argument is filled is one of the Base subclasses. That's ok in my case. However, if I need to make my_class to accept any class, I need to use ``type`` type (my_class: type, ...)

Comment: I try your answer in PyCharm and I get a warning when calling the function: Expected type 'MyClass', got 'Type[SnapshotBookSubscriber]' instead.

Comment: it is wrong - you are checking here that the input is instance of MyClass and not MyClass type itself

Comment: This solution is wrong, this is for instances of MyClass, not classes or subclasses of MyClass. Answer by @roipoussiere is the way to go

Answer (score 140):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44664064), you can use **[Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type)**:

```py
from typing import Type

class X:
    """some class"""

def foo_my_class(my_class: Type[X], bar: str) -> None:
    """ Operate on my_class """
```

Answer (score -6):

I could be wrong, as I haven't been getting down and dirty in Python 3.5 as yet, but looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) you should be able to do it with `typing.Optional`. A brief example.

```
>>> from typing import Optional
>>> 
>>> class MyClass(object):
>>>     def __init__(self):
>>>         self.a = 1
>>> 
>>> O = Optional[MyClass]
>>> 
>>> def test(x: O) -> int:
>>>     return x.a
>>> 
>>> myclass = MyClass()
>>> print test(myclass)
1
```

Hope that helps.