# Correct way use type hints / generics to describe arguments of type class ("type")

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, type-hinting

This appears to be similar to [Type Hinting: Argument Of Type Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387042/type-hinting-argument-of-type-class), however, the accepted answer there does not actually answer my question, so perhaps the question was expressed incorrectly (?)

I have a serialization/deserialization framework that would benefit greatly from [IDE-supported] type hinting.  The API looks something like this:

```
def serialize(obj:BaseModel) -> Dict[str,Any]:
    """ Serialize the object to a dictionary. """

def deserialize(data:Dict[str,Any], clazz:type) -> BaseModel:
    """ Deserialize dictionary into a model object of type clazz. """
```

The serialization method is fine, but deserialize type hinting is not optimal.  I want to indicate that the return value of deserialize will be an object of type `clazz` (which is a subclass of `BaseModel`).  This *seems* like something that generics could help with, but I'm not sure how to express what I want.

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseModel)

def deserialize(data:Dict[str,Any], clazz:T) -> T:
    """ Deserialize dictionary into a model object of type clazz. """
```

This seems wrong since, clazz is a *class* derived from T not an *object* (instance) of type T.

I've done some reading but haven't found an answer (it's also tricky to google this particular problem).  Is there something obvious I'm missing here or is this just not supported by the python 3.5 typing module?

Granted, that I'm still at the mercy of my tooling to infer types, but hopefully if there is a correct way to do this it will be implemented by the type-checking utilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a class can be thought of as a callable that returns and instance of itself, maybe you could try:

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseModel)

def deserialize(data: Dict[str, Any], clazz: Callable[..., T]) -> T:
    """ Deserialize dictionary into a model object of type clazz. """
```

The ellipsis (`...`) means the call signature of the class is unspecified. So a callable object that takes unspecified arguments and returns an instance of `T`.

Comment: Ah, this is a very interesting idea.  I will try that out.  (Though immediately after I typed that I realized that one of my goals here is for my type checker to validate class properties and [class] methods, which seems like it would get lost with that hint.)

Comment: I think you could do that, but you do that as part of the specification of `T` -- by specifying its bound. You can still do runtime checks on the class -- such that the class has all the required fields for the data, but that's beyond the scope of a static type checker.

Comment: I played with this a bit.  While pycharm doesn't seem to support Callable at this time, this appears to be the best (only real?) solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a little tricky with the disconnect between Python and type checker:

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseModel)

def deserialize(etc, T:type) -> T:
```

Then `T` is both your parameter name and your return type. I don't know if your IDE is smart enough to get this, or angry enough to resent it. ;-)