# Type hints with user defined classes

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, user-defined-types

Couldn't seem to find a definitive answer. I want to do a type hint for a function and the type being some custom class that I have defined, called it `CustomClass()`.

And then let's say in some function, call it `FuncA(arg)`, I have one argument named `arg`. Would the correct way to type hint `FuncA` be:

```
def FuncA(arg: CustomClass):
```

Or would it be:

```
from typing import Type

def FuncA(Arg:Type[CustomClass]):
```

Answer (score 273, accepted):

The **former is correct**, if `arg` accepts an **instance of `CustomClass`**:

```
def FuncA(arg: CustomClass):
    #     ^ instance of CustomClass
```

In case you want the **class `CustomClass` itself (or a subtype)**, then you should write:

```
from typing import Type  # you have to import Type

def FuncA(arg: Type[CustomClass]):
    #     ^ CustomClass (class object) itself
```

Like it is written in the documentation about [**Typing**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type):

> ```
> class typing.Type(Generic[CT_co])
> ```
>
> A variable annotated with `C` may accept a value of type `C`. In
>   contrast, a variable **annotated with `Type[C]` may accept values that
>   are classes themselves** - specifically, it will accept the **class
>   object of `C`**.

The documentation includes an example with the `int` class:

> ```
> a = 3         # Has type 'int'
> b = int       # Has type 'Type[int]'
> c = type(a)   # Also has type 'Type[int]'
> ```

Comment: @576i: iirc, you can also use a string. So `def foo(bar: 'Qux')` is equivalent to `def foo(bar: Qux)` except that it does not require loading the type immediately.

Comment: @cs95 Yes. All type hints are +3.7.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Useful! VS Code also supports it with Microsoft's Python Linter, Debugger using Pylance (instead of Jedi) python language server.

Answer (score 33):

Willem Van Onsem's answer is of course correct, but I'd like to offer a small update. In [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/), type hinting  generics were introduced in standard collections. For example, whereas we previously had to say e.g.

```py
from typing import Dict

foo: Dict[str, str] = { "bar": "baz" }
```

we can now forgo the parallel type hierarchy in the `typing` module and simply say

```py
foo: dict[str, str] = { "bar": "baz" }
```

This feature is available in python 3.9+, and also in 3.7+ if using `from __future__ import annotations`.

In terms of this specific question, it means that instead of `from typing import Type`, we can now simply annotate classes using the built-in `type`:

```py
def FuncA(arg: type[CustomClass]):
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for Python 3.9 since use of [`typing.Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) shown in Willem Van Onsem's answer is deprecated.