# How to add type hinting to "class" type in python

Tags: python, type-hinting

```
# Java
public <T> T findById(String id, Class<T> clazz)
```

How should the `Class<T>` type in the above Java method signature be represented by Python type hint?

```
# Python
def find_by_id(id: str, clazz: ???) -> T
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type hints with user defined classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664040/type-hints-with-user-defined-classes)

Comment: Not a dupe IMO. That question is, at best, ambiguous about whether it asks for the instance or the class. This one is explicit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To annotate the type of a class itself, use [`Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type).

```
class AClass:
    ...


def a_function(a_string: str, a_class: type[AClass]) -> None:
    ...
```

Since a class is a type, the class name can be an annotation itself:

```
def a_class_factory(a_class: type[AClass], *args, **kwargs) -> AClass:
    return a_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: since Python 3.9, [`Type` is deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.Type) and `type` should be used now.