# Python: Fixed type argument from a class

Tags: python-3.x, oop, types

To fix the type of the argument of a method (function) I can declare a variable like this:

```py
def function_name(parameter1: type) -> return_type:
    ...

# for instance
def function_name(parameter1: int) -> str:
    ...
# parameter1 must be an integer and returns a string
```

but if I define a class, how can I fix the argument (or the return type) of the function as a variable from a type class. For instance:

```py
class MyClass:
    __init__(self):
        ...

def function_name(parameter1: MyClass) -> str:
    ...
```

I get an error:

```
Undefined name 'MyClass'
```

Comment: That doesn't enforce a type... Its just a type hint for programmers to use. It doesn't enforce anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hints with user defined classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664040/type-hints-with-user-defined-classes)

Comment: And is there a way to enforce a type?

Comment: You should ideally not enforce types in python. It is a strong typed language, its power comes in its typing dont try to turn python into a typed language like Java.  If you want to make sure an object is of a certain type you can use something like `if isinstance(my_obj, str)` but I would only do that when truly needed.  Type hinting is a good idea though, but it is just a form of documentation, unless you use something like MyPy (which is what I think you are trying to do).