# How to define the type of a dictionary of classes for mypy?

Tags: python, types, mypy

I have several classes that use static methods to implement behaviour. I collect them in a python dictionary. How do I write down the type of the dictionary for mypy? Example below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


from typing import Dict
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
import enum


class Cuties(enum.Enum):
    Doggo = enum.auto()
    Kitty = enum.auto()
    Birb = enum.auto()


class Animal(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def give_sound() -> str:
        ...

    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def likes_ferrets(ferret_fur_colour: str) -> bool:
        ...


class Doggo_Specifics(Animal):

    @staticmethod
    def give_sound() -> str:
        return 'woofle'

    @staticmethod
    def likes_ferrets(ferret_fur_colour: str) -> bool:
        return False


class Kitty_Specifics(Animal):

    @staticmethod
    def give_sound() -> str:
        return 'meow'

    @staticmethod
    def likes_ferrets(ferret_fur_colour: str) -> bool:
        return True


class Birb_Specifics(Animal):

    @staticmethod
    def give_sound() -> str:
        return 'peep'

    @staticmethod
    def likes_ferrets(ferret_fur_colour: str) -> bool:
        return ferret_fur_colour == 'brown'


Specifics: Dict[Cuties, Animal] = {
    Cuties.Doggo: Doggo_Specifics,
    Cuties.Kitty: Kitty_Specifics,
    Cuties.Birb: Birb_Specifics,
}
```

mypy gives errors for the type of `Specifics`:

```
test.py:62: error: Dict entry 0 has incompatible type "Cuties": "Type[Doggo_Specifics]"; expected "Cuties": "Animal"
test.py:63: error: Dict entry 1 has incompatible type "Cuties": "Type[Kitty_Specifics]"; expected "Cuties": "Animal"
test.py:64: error: Dict entry 2 has incompatible type "Cuties": "Type[Birb_Specifics]"; expected "Cuties": "Animal"
```

How should I define the type of `Specifics`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hints with user defined classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664040/type-hints-with-user-defined-classes)

Comment: As the duplicate says, you should import `Type` from `typing` and type your dict as `Specifics: Dict[Cuties, Type[Animal]] = {...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, different idea. Even though this code runs on my machine, it warns me about possible type mismatch. I've found a way that takes care of that warning, even it may look stupid. Try adding "**class**" to Animal:

```
Specifics: Dict[Cuties, Animal.__class__] = {
    Cuties.Doggo: Doggo_Specifics,
    Cuties.Kitty: Kitty_Specifics,
    Cuties.Birb: Birb_Specifics,
}
```

Comment: This does not pass mypy checks without erros for me: `test.py:61: error: Function "builtins.object.__class__" is not valid as a type`