# python type hinting type as input

Tags: python, types, type-hinting

I want to use python type hinting and define a parameter as the `datatype`. The best would be to only allow `str`, `int`, `float`, `bool`, or `None` (but I guess that is the value of the `datatype`, not the type, I can check that manually). How do I do this?

---

I have a function like the following:

```py
import typing

Savable = typing.Union[str, int, float, bool, None]
Datatype = type.Any # <- what should I use?

def save_variable_persistent(key: str, value: Savable, datatype: Datatype) -> bool:
    # save the variable in some way where I **have** to know the datatype, 
    # for reserving the space
    pass

def load_variable_persistent(key: str, datatype: Datatype):
    # load the value from some backend interface which **needs** to know the type
    pass
```

I don't know how to define the `Datatype` to allow types only.

---

## What I did

**Thought 1 (wrong)**: Use `typing.Union[int, str, ...]`, but that doesn't make sense, because that will allow to instances of int and str. This will make `datatype` to be the same as `Savable` which is wrong.

**Thought 2 (wrong)**: When I use python and type

```
>>> int
<class 'int'>
```

<del>it sais `int` is an instance of the `int`-class (?). So I need to have a `typing. Union` that allows instances of the `int`-class plus instances of the `str`-class and so on (?). But instances of the `int`-class are integers, so numbers. And instances of the `str` class are the strings itself. Also, this means to use `typing. Union[int, str, ...]` so I come back to being equal to `Savable` again.</del>

**Thought 3**: On [python docs about typing at the section `typing.Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) it sais, that `int` is a `typing.Type`. That means I should use `typing.Type` for `Datatype`. Also `type(int) == typing.Type` returns `True`.

**Thought 4**: Using `type(int)` returns `<class 'type'>`. But `typing.Type == type` returns `False`.

3 and 4 make me think that both, `typing.Type` and `type` are just classes that contain the information of e.g. `int` but are not the type/class of `int`.

---

So, what should I use? `Datatype = typing.Type`, `Datatype = type` or something completely different?

Comment: "it sais int is an instance of the int-class" - no, it says that `int` is a class named "int".

Comment: Are you trying to describe *generics*, that Savable and Database should have matching types?

Comment: Why is `datatype` an argument at all? It sounds like you could just use `type(value)`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Because I might have values that can be `int`s and `float`s. If I get the `int` value I still have to know that it is possible that this value can be a `float` too. In addition I need that for the other way around so I know how many bytes to load. But that is very specific to the function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe They match in most of the cases, check out my comment above. But that is not my main goal, I just want to have `datatype` to allow types as input only.

Comment: It seems like it'd make more sense to pass an actual float, rather than pretending an int is a float and passing an extra argument to treat it like a float. `foo('blah', float(float_or_int))` rather than `foo('blah', float_or_int, float)`.

Comment: For setting the value that acutally makes sense. But I also need the `load_value()` function and I need to know what to load, which datatype. I can't do that in python because of the system I am communicating with. It needs to know the datatype.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hints with user defined classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664040/type-hints-with-user-defined-classes) `typing.Type` works for built-in types as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition that `typing.Type` was the right place to look is correct. The docs are pretty good here, even if they don't explain things like why `type!=typing.Type`.

- Use `type` (or equivalently `Type` or `Type[Any]`, even though an `==` comparison indicates they're different) if you want to allow any type.
- Use `Type[Union[str, int, etc]]` if you want to covariantly allow any of a fixed set of types.
- Use `Type[T]` if you want to use generics (e.g. `def foo(a: T, a_type: Type[T])`) (look up TypeVar if you don't know how to use generics yet).