# Passing an exception type as argument, how to type hint?

Tags: python, exception, type-hinting

I have a function which takes an exception class as an argument, this is the simplified version

```py
def catch_exception(exception):
    try:
        1/0
    except exception:
        print("lol")
```

```
>>> catch_exception(exception=ZeroDivisionError)
lol
```

Type hinting this should be easy:

```py
def catch_exception(exception: Exception):
    ...
```

but when I then use this function, I get a problem from the IDE (PyCharm)

```py
catch_exception(exception=ZeroDivisionError)  
# Expected type 'Exception', got 'Type[Exception]' instead
```

I understand the problem, I am passing an exception CLASS not an exception INSTANCE.
At the same time I am not sure how to type hint in way that is both formally correct and that has got documentation value for the user.

The following seems to work but there must be a better way:

```py
def catch_exception(exception: Type[Exception]):
    ...
```

Comment: The current approach looks fine to me.

Comment: `Type[<Type>]` is indeed the correct and preferred way to do this. This question covers the general case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664040/type-hints-with-user-defined-classes

Answer (score 0):

Your way is the correct and best way to do this.
If you need an exception class you need to use `Type[Exception]`. Using just `Exception` just would be wrong.

So there is no better way to do this than:

```
def catch_exception(exception: Type[Exception]):
    ...
```