# Python typing: Narrowing the scope of output subclass instance by base class parameter

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I found this difficult to describe without an example.

```python
from typing import List, Type, Optional, cast

class Base():
    kind = 'base'
class Child1(Base):
    kind = 'child1'
class Child2(Base):
    kind = 'child2'
class Child3(Base):
    kind = 'child3'

def find_in_list(lst: List[Base], SearchClass: Type[Base]): # Return Optional[??]
    for obj in lst: # type: Base
        if obj.kind == SearchClass.kind:
          return obj
    return None

lst = [Child1(), Child2(), Child3()]
def func2(c: Child2) -> None:
    assert isinstance(c, Child2)
res2_opt: Optional[Child2] = find_in_list(lst, Child2)
if res2_opt:
    func2(res2_opt)


def func3(c: Child3) -> None:
    assert isinstance(c, Child3)
res3_opt: Optional[Child3] = find_in_list(lst, Child2) # Should be Error!
if res3_opt:
    func3(res3_opt) # Is AssertionError
```

Because the return type of `find_in_list` is too open, mypy doesn't consider anything to be wrong with this, yet it at runtime correctly hits the assertion error. I tried `-> Optional[SearchClass]`, but it (correctly) doesn't recognize that as a type.

It should be possible to narrow the scope of the return type of `find_in_list` to be parameterized the same as or the same way as `SearchClass` is, such that if you pass in `Child2` as a parameter, you can restrict the output to be `Optional[Child2]`. How can this be done?

Comment: Note: the next closest SO question to this is [this one on typing class parameterizations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33387042/6069586), but this extends that to parameterizing over both the base class and a specific subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Generic function using `TypeVar` and cast the return value:

```
from typing import TypeVar, cast
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Base)
def find_in_list(lst: List[Base], SearchClass: Type[T]) -> Optional[T]:
    for obj in lst:
        if obj.kind == SearchClass.kind:
            return cast(T, obj)
    return None
```

Then:

```
res3_opt: Optional[Child3] = find_in_list(lst, Child2)
# Mypy: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Optional[Child2]", 
# variable has type "Optional [Child3]")
```

Comment: Thanks! Mostly leaning on just the typing module docs, and stackoverflow, this wasn't obvious to me. Looking at your answer, and realizing the key to keeping type `T` (which is the same between input parameterization and output parameterization) limited to the generic bound `Base` of the other input parameterization, is parameterizing `T` itself. This method also implies it's not possible to do this purely in the function def, requiring a pre-parameterized TypeVar `T`. For future seekers: the typing module docs barely mention TypeVar(bound), but PEP 484 has many more examples. Thanks again!